# ADAL ASP.NET MVC and Angular. Login from ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, oauth-2.0, adal, adal.js

I have an application already written in ASP.NET MVC. We have decided to write new frontend functions in angular and slowly migrate all frontend to angular. But for now we are stuck with both Angular and MVC. The problem we have is that when a user logs on the login is only made on the MVC parts of the application. The access token from the Azure AD is not shared between Angular and ASP.NET MVC.

I have installed 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5

I can login with that package from angular page but I want to reuse the login from the MVC side. Is that possible?

I have made a authentication module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from '../services/authenticated.guard';
import { Adal5Service, Adal5HTTPService } from 'adal-angular5';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OAuthCallbackHandler } from '../oauth-callback/oauth-callback.guard';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [ CommonModule, HttpClientModule ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [
        AuthenticationGuard,
        Adal5Service,
        {
            provide: Adal5HTTPService,
            useFactory: Adal5HTTPService.factory,
            deps: [ HttpClient, Adal5Service ]
        },
        OAuthCallbackHandler
    ],

})
export class AuthenticationModule
{
    constructor(private adalService: Adal5Service)
    {
        this.adalService.init({
            tenant: 'tenant',
            clientId: 'my-id',
            redirectUri: 'mycallback uri',
            postLogoutRedirectUri: 'some redirect uri',
            popUp: true

        });
    }
}
```

I can later call

```
this.adalService.login();
```

This logs me in but I don't want to force the users to log in in twice.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the new angular ui in a separate project from the Asp.Net MVC application?

Comment: It is on the same domain.

Comment: How did your enable authentication in your ASP.NET MVC backend? The authentication middleware in your backend may could not validate the authentication token from your client side via ADAL, so your application would force the client users to log in again, you may need to adjust the authentication middleware in your backend. Please provide more details about your scenario. And you could follow my answer, any concerns, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Sorry bruce chen I haven't had time to test your solution. I will let you know when I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your MVC application may uses [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) middleware for AAD authentication and here is a related tutorial [Integrate Azure AD into a web application using OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/). For this approach, the logged user claims would be encrypted into cookie and return to the client.

Since you have change the frontend to angular, you'd better use ADAL library to directly retrieve the access_token or id_token and send it as bearer token to your backend for authentication, and your backend need to use [Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/) for for supporting AAD JWT bearer token authentication as follows:

```html
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = "{AAD-client-ID}"
        },
        Tenant = "{tenantID}"
    });
```

Details you could follow [Azure AD .NET Web API getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet).

> I can login with that package from angular page but I want to reuse the login from the MVC side. Is that possible?

You could combine Cookies and Bearer authentication in your ASP.NET MVC application. **Note:** You need to enable bearer token authentication prior to Cookie authentication. If your backend and frontend host in the same website, then you could reuse the cookie, I assume that before you execute `this.adalService.login();`, you could try to send a request to your backend for validating that whether a validated cookie has been issued to the browser. If you get 200 status code, then you do not need to login in your frontend via ADAL, and you could set a flag in your fontend to mark that the current user has logged from the backend, **Note:** the cookie may has the expire time. While you get 401 or error, you may need to explicitly execute `this.adalService.login();` in your frontend. When sending request to your backend fro retrieving normal data, you may need to check the login flag, and add the Authorization header with the value `Bearer <access-token>` when the current user has marked as logged from the frontend.

**Note:** The above scenario may exists some problems and you need to handle the access_token or cookie expiration issue. I would recommend you just use a single authentication approach.