# Using ADAL.JS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I'm looking for some pointers which has integration of MVC application with adal.js and web api call. My question is similar to [ADAL ASP.NET MVC and Angular. Login from ASP .NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249965/adal-asp-net-mvc-and-angular-login-from-asp-net-mvc) . 
We have production running MVC application, we have to update this application to make call to another WEB API instead of web api hosted in same application/domain url. TO call API of different domain, we are planning to make use of ADAL.JS but every time

```js
authContext.acquireToken(authContext.config.clientId, function (error, token)
{// Handle ADAL Error 
if (error || !token) 
{
console.log('ADAL Error Occurred: ' + error);return;
}
else 
{
console.log('Bearer ' + token);
}}
```

or

```
var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
if (user) {
      console.log("User found");

} else {
    console.log("error");
   authContext.config.redirectUri = window.location.href;
   authContext.login();
}
```

I'm getting error message "user required to login". Question here is, User is already authenticated through MVC & we also enabled Cookie Authentication in startup.cs which should store access token in cookie, but i couldn't see access token in browser cookies, but every time we call getCacheUser it is empty. or calling acquiretoken is redirecting to login screen. Is there any better way of implementing adal.js with MVC and Call another WEB API from angular JS.

Comment: Appreciate any help on this

Comment: How did you go? You can't use the token acquired from auth flow on the server for client side requests. To get a JWT token your end user needs to perform the login from their browser. Once this is done, you can pass the token up to the server and use it to make server side requests with. I would suggest getting rid of your cookie based auth flow and moving over to JWT all the way. You can swap middle wares fairly easily and any user info that you had in the cookie can be added as a claim for the rest of the pipeline.